# Rigging my First Model - How do I IK rig the legs?

Tags: rigging

This is my first character model I have made and am trying to rig. It is nothing complicated as I am trying to learn how to create and rig a character before trying to make things complicated. However, I can't figure out how to IK rig my character's leg. I have been following
[this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9f-WVs3ghI), but once I get to the Leg ik.L bone things start to mess up such as the bone separating or the whole leg twisting  to the right and left of the model very strangely. So, I decided to change the foot to a more simple style and I was hoping somebody would be able to help me IK rig the leg and foot.

[image: My First Rig]

Also, I plan on using the mirror modifier or tool to mirror the bones to the right side of the model.

Comment: You should attach your .blend file to show how have your rig twist or turn strangely. Use the link http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/